# Issue regarding logging the pose object in posenet of tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

When I run the above code only the pose object of the last image is logged 5 times.

I want to log the pose object of each image.
I am using the http-server of node.js

There is no error in the following code, Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
    <!-- Load Posenet -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id='cat' crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <button onclick="myfun()">button</button>
    <script>
        function myfun() {
            arr = ["http://127.0.0.1:8080/pic1.jpeg", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pic2.jpeg", "http:  //127.0.0.1:8080/pic3.jpeg", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pic4.jpeg", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pic5.jpeg"]
            var x;
            for (x of arr) {
                document.getElementById("cat").src = x;
                var flipHorizontal = false;
                var imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');
                imageElement.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
                posenet.load({
                    architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
                    outputStride: 16
                }).then(function(net) {
                    const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
                        flipHorizontal: true
                    });
                    return pose;
                }).then(function(pose) {
                    console.log(pose);
                })
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the for loop is running async operation. By the time both posenet calls have resolved, the image has been set to the last item of the for loop.

Using `async ... await` will prevent to have the posenet estimation only for the last item of the loop.

```
async function myfun() {
        arr = ["http://127.0.0.1:8080/pic1.jpeg", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pic2.jpeg", "http:  //127.0.0.1:8080/pic3.jpeg", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pic4.jpeg", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pic5.jpeg"]
        var x;
        for (x of arr) {
            document.getElementById("cat").src = x;
            var flipHorizontal = false;
            var imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');
            imageElement.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                imageElement.onload = _ => {
                    resolve(imageElement)
                }
            })
            const net = await posenet.load({
                architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
                outputStride: 16
            })

            const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(await p, {
                flipHorizontal: true
            });

            console.log(pose);
        }
```

Additionnaly, the model could be loaded before running the loop. A single instance of the model can be used for all estimations.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code works correctly just needed to modify the first line of the async function by adding the name of the array as **arr**

Comment: Yes, it is a typo, i fixed. Glad to see that it helped. You can upvote the answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: while estimating estimating the single pose in the above code we are setting the flipHorizontal to be true but I think it should be true only for a video am I right

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop from `for (x of arr) {` to `for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
x = arr[x];
...
...
}`

And it will work as it should.